# How to make plot data with Date yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss?

Tags: r, datetime, plot

I have a set of data need to be plotted with R. I need to make dot graphics with value as an axis y and date with time as a y. But first i want to plot in one date (ex. 2018.10.29 10:10:12 - 2018.10.29 23:59:01) and next around one week and then one month etc. I have data frame and file.csv too as my data source. i have 2 date format on my data, and maybe i must to change tht so the date format will be in one format. Could you please help me? I am a newbie in R and i try to learn it. Thank you for your help.

Below is a short example of the data:

```
ID  Date    Location    CO2 Temp    Hum Light   Soil    Soil2                                                   
1   10/29/2018 12:11    EE_agri8    557.8357    23.90000    45.00000    41.0000 99.55399    99.67636    
2   10/29/2018 12:12    EE_agri8    557.8357    23.90000    45.50000    41.0000 99.55399    99.67636    
3   10/29/2018 12:11    EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    99.55399    99.67636    
4   2018-10-29 12:13:16 EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    73.07000    99.67636    
5   2018-10-29 16:57:35 EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    99.55399    99.67636    
6   10/29/2018 12:12    EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    99.55399    99.67636    23.8600 24.0549
7   10/29/2018 12:13    EE_agri8    557.8357    24.00000    45.40000    41.0000 99.55399    99.67636    
8   2018-10-29 12:14:20 EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    72.15000    99.67636    
9   2018-10-29 17:01:04 EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    99.55399    99.67636    
10  10/30/2018 12:12    EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    99.55399    99.67636    
11  10/30/2018 12:14    EE_agri8    557.8357    24.20000    45.40000    41.0000 99.55399    99.67636    
12  2018-10-30 12:15:23 EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    72.84000    99.67636    
13  2018-10-30 17:02:14 EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    99.55399    99.67636    
14  10/31/2018 12:13    EE_agri8    557.8357    25.84484    70.24592    508.5654    99.55399    99.67636
```

Comment: You should ask this in 2 questions. The first would be on the data cleaning/date harmonisation and the second on how to produce the plots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parsedate` function that attempts to detect the date format, then with some wrangling you can use `facet_grid` in ggplot2 to break the data up into the desired groupings:

```
library(dplyr)
library(parsedate)

# Parse dates
(df <- df %>%
    mutate(Date = parse_date(Date),
           time = format(Date, "%H:%M:%S"), # Strips date from Date
           day = format(Date, "%Y/%m/%d"), # strips time from Date
           month = format(Date, "%Y/%m"), # format by year/month
           week = strftime(Date, format = "%V") # finds the week of year the date falls into
           ))

# By Day
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = Soil)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(day~.)

# By Week
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Soil)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(week~.)

# By Month
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Soil)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(month~.)
```

Comment: dear Paul, i didnt have ggplot function, so i got an error. what should i do? Thank you

Comment: `install.packages("ggplot2")`, mate.